# Just display notification without start the activity

Tags: android, notifications

i'm try to develop an app for organizing . so after setting an task for particular time, i  created a notification, so this notification displays on the status bar and when the user touch on this, current activity will appear.
My problem is : when the notification appear, the activity is launched also.
there is anyways to prevent this ? i mean the activity don't start automatically when the notification appear, and the user have to click on the notification to wake the activity up.

I have class "Main" and an alarm manager inside. this alarm manager will fire at the particular time and start an another activity (DisplayNotification).

```
{
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.test.DisplayNotification");
    intent.putExtra("alarm_message", "Alarm");
    intent.putExtra("item_name", "message");
    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mili, broadcast);
}
```

In the DisplayNotification class i have

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String message = getIntent().getExtras().getString("item_name");

        Intent i = new Intent("com.test.Main");


        PendingIntent detailsIntent = 
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)
            getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notif = new Notification(
            R.drawable.icon, 
            "Time's up!",
            System.currentTimeMillis());

        CharSequence from = "AlarmManager - Time's up!";
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, detailsIntent);


        nm.notify(1, notif);
        //---destroy the activity---
        finish();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `BroadcastReceiver` to 'listen' for the result of the alarm and then have it create the `Notification` in its `onReceive(...)` method.

Comment: I have just think about this before, but i have some problem on get the context, but it's ok now, thank for take me out of the mud

Comment: @Trần Đức Anh: Glad I could help.